# What is the difference between char array[100]; and char array[100] = "";?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am trying to write a C program that loads a file, reads it and outputs the longest line from the file together with the number of symbols. The result is written in another file. The code seems to be working like it is, but I would like to understand why I get wrong results once I slightly change the definition of the arrays, to remove the equals to empty quotes (`= ""`) from the `maxLine` definition. For example, if I write the following:

```
char currentLine[100]; 
char maxLine[100];
```

then I get unwanted results.

Here is the whole function:

```
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 50

void maxCharRow()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    errno_t err;

    char fileNameRead[MAX_FILE_NAME] = "test.txt";
    char fileNameWrite[MAX_FILE_NAME] = "results.txt";
    char currentLine[100]; 
    char maxLine[100] = "";  

    if ((err = fopen_s(&fptr, fileNameRead, "r")) != NULL) {
        printf("Could not open the file: %s\n", fileNameRead);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(currentLine, sizeof(currentLine), fptr) != NULL)
    {
        if (strlen(maxLine) < strlen(currentLine))
        {
            strcpy_s(maxLine, currentLine);
        }
    }
    printf("\nLongest line in file has %i symbols\nand its content is:%s", strlen(maxLine), maxLine);

    ((err = fopen_s(&fptr, fileNameWrite, "w")) != NULL); {
        fprintf(fptr, "%s", maxLine);
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: `if (strlen(maxLine)...` requires `maxLine` to be initialized which it is not if you just do `char maxLine[100];`

Comment: with `char maxLine[100] = "";` with end up with an array where all 100 elements are `'\0'`; with `char maxLine[100];` you end up with an array where the contents of the elements can be anything (even, maybe in strange architectures, illegal).

Comment: This `strcpy_s(maxLine, currentLine);` looks wrong. This function ought be called with three parameters: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.7.1.3

Comment: It might look wrong, but it works normally just like strcpy when you don't specify the size. I use it simply because visual studio does not like strcpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c `""` is an empty  string terminated by null character `0`.

Since char `currentLine[100]` is a local variable it is by default not initialized to zero and is filled with indeterminate values.

But if you initialize zero-th element to `0` or `""` then c will initialize whole array with zeros.

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr0[100];
    char arr1[100] = "";
    char arr2[100] = {0};

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        printf("%d ", arr0[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -75 -16 0 0 0 0 0 -62 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -89 -82 55 -96 -4 127 0 0 -90 -82 55 -96 -4 127 0 0 85 -105 -84 -34 -92 127 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 101 88 74 28 -111 85 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 88 74 28 -111 85 0 0 -48 85 74 28 -111 85 0 0 -80 -81 55 -96 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Edit:

Also note that even if you set first eg. 3 elements to non-zero values `char arr0[100] = {1,2,3}` the rest of the elements will still be initialized to zero.

Comment: a more precise term for "garbage values" here would be "indeterminate values" because they can actually change over time.

Comment: This `for(int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        printf("%d ", arr0[i]);
    }` reads  "indeterminate values", which in turn *could* provoke the infamous Undefined Behaviour. As a rule of thumb: **Never** read out uninitialised variables, as it is dangerous and there is absolutely no reason to do this, never.

Comment: To be fully accurate replace "*set*" by "initialise". Because this `arr0[0] = 0` also *set*s the 1st element of `arr0` to `0` but does **not** touch **any** of the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `""` to an array null-terminates the array so it becomes a string.

It's like doing this:

```
char array[100] = { '\0' };
```

Note that this isn't needed at global scope because variables at global scope are already zero-initialized.

Comment: You're correct, just a note: `char array[100] = { '\0' };` sets all elements to `'\0'` (`array[0] = '\0'; /* explicitly */ array[1] = array[2] = ... array[99] = 0;`).